# Extract unique words from text file

Tags: python

1. Find out the number of unique dialogue speakers in the sample conversation?
2. Create a new text file by the name of the dialogue speaker and store the unique words spoken by that character in the respective text file. Make sure there is only one word every line.

I've a long transcript as txt file. Example :

```
WILL: I’ve never seen wildlings do a thing like this. I’ve never seen a thing like this, not ever in my life.
WAYMAR ROYCE: How close did you get?
WILL: Close as any man would.
GARED: We should head back to the wall.
ROYCE: Do the dead frighten you?
GARED: Our orders were to track the wildlings. We tracked them. They won’t trouble us no more.

......continue.....
```

I tried refindall, split and partition but nothing is working.
Using Jupyter Notebook latest version 2023

Comment: All the conversations are in the same line? No line break (\n) here? If the txt file isn't too large and you have the right to share it. You could upload the txt file to Google Drive and paste the link here so that people can see what the original txt file looks like

Comment: No, it's in line by line format like usual chat transcripts. 
Yes, when I read it output comes with (\n) .

Comment: Show the code you tried, what you expected vs. current result and/or error traceback so we can suggest corrections.  This is not a coding service and you are expected to show your coding attempt.

Comment: Looks like a homework. Is it?

Comment: No, I'm a beginner and learning from online sources. Came across with this problem statement and struggling with it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called `transcript.txt` containing the dialogue you shared:

```
WILL: I’ve never seen wildlings do a thing like this. I’ve never seen a thing like this, not ever in my life.
WAYMAR ROYCE: How close did you get?
WILL: Close as any man would.
GARED: We should head back to the wall.
ROYCE: Do the dead frighten you?
GARED: Our orders were to track the wildlings. We tracked them. They won’t trouble us no more.

......continue.....
```

I then read the text file, split the contents into lines,
extracted the unique dialogue speakers and their dialogues, and I created a new text file for each speaker, storing their unique words. Here is my code which I tested on Google Colab:

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict

# Read the text file
with open('transcript.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

# Split the content into lines
lines = content.split('\n')

# Extract unique dialogue speakers and their dialogues
dialogues = defaultdict(str)
for line in lines:
    match = re.match(r'^(.+?):\s*(.+)$', line)
    if match:
        speaker, dialogue = match.groups()
        dialogues[speaker] += dialogue + ' '

# Process each speaker's dialogues
for speaker, dialogue in dialogues.items():
    # Extract unique words
    words = set(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', dialogue.lower()))
    
    # Create a new text file and store unique words
    with open(f'{speaker}.txt', 'w') as file:
        for word in sorted(words):
            file.write(f'{word}\n')
```